# Some characters typed on the keyboard are not in AZERTY?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm quite newbie but i have a problem running a Contabo VPS server that i use with Gnome Desktop and Ubuntu 22.04, some characters do not seem to use my QWERTY keyboard (i need to use AZERTY), for example the letter M appears in , or the letter q appears in a while others letters work, how to solve this problem?
Thank you for your help

---

To be more specific, I have a Linux VPS server with Ubuntu 20.04 and Gnome. I use PuTTy for my command lines and UltraVNC Viewer for the GUI.My problem is that when I type on the keyboard of my laptop which is in AZERTY some characters are displayed differently in Gnome for example:

q = a / w = z /m = ; -: , / ; = , / ! = & / & = è

The entire top part of my computer keyboard from the '&' character to the 'à' character does not match. I don't understand where it can come from!

Comment: How about adding a QWERTY keyboard layout to your laptop and switch to it when interacting with the server?